# fastapi.Response() not returning customized response

Tags: python, api, http, fastapi

```
api = fastapi.FastAPI()

@api.get('/api/sum')

def caculate(z):

    if z == 0 :
        return fastapi.Response(content = {'Error' : 'Z must be an integer'},
        status_code=400,
        media_type="application/json")
    return

uvicorn.run(api, host="127.0.0.50", port=8000) #server
```

I am trying to return the response as mentioned in the content and a 400 http response. But it is giving me a 200 response and also giving me 'null' instead of the content.

[image: output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide a type to the query param and use `JSONResponse` as the return If you want the object to be returned as json or serialize the data yourself `json.dumps()` if you want to use `Response`.

```py
  def caculate(z: int=0):
      if z == 0 :
          return fastapi.responses.JSONResponse(content = {'Error' : 'Z must be an integer'},status_code=400)
```

Comment: Thank you,it works. But could you please help me in understanding why using Response it doesn't return the same? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/ -as it says

Comment: @RahulDey, updated my answer since I forgot to mention the query param which was why you were getting the 200, Response directly responds with the data you provide therefore it needs to be a string.